# Journeyman Geek's Monthly Bounty Hunt: August/September

Tags: discussion, bounty-hunt

And.. The second installment of the bounty hunt. I was away most of the time, but I'm sure *someone else* remembered this ;).

The ground rules are the same as last month, and yes, I still want suggestions on what would be worthy candidates for a bounty hunt.

Post the questions you think should get the bounty and why

A few ground rules in place to avoid drama... I'll post these every monthly bounty hunt, and change these as needed.

I'd like to avoid self answers - if you can answer the question, you should do it without a bounty to encourage you.

You can recommend any question, not just your own.

Selection of a question is at my discretion. I'll be awarding a minimum of 50 rep per month. If i can't find anything i like, that 50 rep gets rolled over to the next month. I may pick more questions or give more rep to an answer if i choose to. I suppose my offered bounty tab may be a guideline, but I don't ONLY do hardware questions

Questions should be bountiable, and should be worth bountying. This means older questions with no answers, or ones where i can be convinced a bounty will get a quality answer. I'd like stuff that could do with a good, canonical answer.

I'll check back at this post - I'll pick the first question around the Last week of august or the first week of september, and pick one to give a bounty for. I reserve the right to edit the post if I made any silly errors like i did last month ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Change Linux Console's Default Monitor](https://superuser.com/q/122173/83694)

I have a laptop with an external monitor, and the laptop's native screen doesn't usually face me.  When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, the console displays on the laptop screen.  ****sigh****  Now I gotta get out of my seat...

Surely I'm not the only one bothered by situations like this.

Comment: actually.. I like this one.

Comment: Oh, I don't have a suitable system to test this, so if you could help me test the answers given, it would be easier for me to decide who to give the bounty to.

Answer (score 3):

### [Is there a chat log archiver that can import logs from multiple clients?](https://superuser.com/q/343357/83694)

Chat Log Converter+, the only chat log converter in the world (as far as I found), ceased to exist.  I've been searching for a new solution ever since... even before the question was asked.

A chat log converter is an important step to personal data management.  Since chat clients are specialized (Facebook Chat, Google Talk, Skype, Windows Live Messenger, etc.), a chat log converter would be very useful for furthering development of managing logs.

From there, software can be written to search and manipulate chat logs.

---

This question is worth putting a bounty on because somebody might have something (development work, software, scripts) that I don't.  I've been searching for a long time.

Comment: http://forum.digsby.com/viewtopic.php?id=8039

Answer (score 2):

[How can I send a message to my cellphone when someone logs onto my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/466383/laptop-login-notification-message-to-my-cellphone/466391#466391)

Ok, while I answered this, a better, less.. hackish solution would be nice. (and no, this might not be the question I pick. Just popped it in here cause I might forget ;p)